# Given a Tic-Tac-Toe gamestate return all wins as text

Tags: python, game, tic-tac-toe

In a game of *Tic-TacToe* given a gamestate:

```
game_board = [ [1, 0, 1],
               [0, 1, 0],
               [0, 1, 0] ]
```

I have written the following piece of code to display the output of the gamestate in regards to wins:

```
game_board = [ [1, 1, 1],
               [0, 1, 0],
               [0, 1, 0] ]

# Horizontals
h = [str(i+1) + ' Row' for i, v in enumerate(game_board) if sum(v) == 3]

# Verticals
v = [str(i+1) + ' Col' for i in range(3) if sum([j[i] for j in game_board]) == 3]

# Diagonals
d = [['Left Diag', '','Right Diag'][i+1] for i in [-1, 1] if sum([game_board[0][1+i], game_board[1][1]], game_board[2][1-i]) == 3]

if any([h,v,d]):
    print('You won on:', h, v, d)
else:
    print('No win yet')
```

The output of this is:

```
You won on: ['1 Row'] ['2 Col'] []
```

I would like to know how my solution could be written in a more Pythonic manner?

Comment: I would do `['Row 1'], ['Col 2'], []` but that's just me.

Comment: @Linny - good suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about whether a solution could be more `Pythonic`, but I think it can be more efficient.  At present your code is iterating over each cell twice, before anything is printed.

I would suggest using a collection of possible winning strings.  You only need to iterate over the cells once and each time you encounter a `0` that row, col and if applicable, diagonal become invalid as a winning line.

After that, it's a simple matter of iterating over the strings and printing the ones that are valid.

Comment: I like that approach and it makes sense -- I'll have a try with that idea

Comment: So a `0` in the center eliminates the possibility of a win in the diagonals and crosses, then a `0` in a corner will eliminate the corresponding row-column - thanks for the valuable answer

Comment: @leopardxpreload - Just an fyi for you.  If row == col the cell belongs to left diag.  If row + col == 2 it belongs to the right diag.